# Windows 10 icon names not wrapping after resolution and scaling changes

Tags: windows-10, scaling, desktop-icons

I changed the scaling and resolution of my monitor but it somehow messed up the icon names on my desktop. I have tried resetting and changing desktop theme but nothing seems to work. Icon names are not wrapping and I cannot find any setting to fix this.

[image]

I have set the icons on auto-arrange and auto-align but they are spread out all over the desktop, with their full names being displayed. I am *assuming* that the issue is with wrapping of icon names but I don't know exactly what is happening. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: At leat two of them **are** wrapping. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @DavidPostill You are right. I did not notice that some icon names are wrapping. I guess the spacing between icons has increased somehow.

Comment: [Change Desktop Icon Spacing in Windows 10 | Tutorials](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16941-change-desktop-icon-spacing-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not the wrapping, it's the icon spacing. You can tinker with these settings by editing the following registry keys:

> - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\IconSpacing

and

> - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\IconVerticalSpacing

(the default values are `-1128`) and you may also have luck just going to Control Panel > File Explorer Options > View tab > and then clicking the "Restore Defaults" button.

Reference: [Tom's Hardware](https://forums.tomshardware.com/faq/how-to-change-icon-spacing-in-windows-10-desktop.2702636/)

Comment: The default settings are -1128 for both horizontal and vertical spacing of icons as shown in the tutorial shared by David Postill in the comment section of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem even though I didn't change resolution scaling. The registry showed the default values as well which was really weird. I keep this on hand as it's easier. Also you don't need to restart, just logout.

downloadinformer.com/desktop-icons-spacing-controller-2-1-for-windows-108-17/

Answer (score 0):

I had that exact same issue after upgrading to the latest Windows 10 release 1909.
The icons spacing was messed up. Icons in programs looked wacked too.

Also from time to time for no reason my system DPI changes. I suspect bad GPU or a bad displayport cable.

There's a small program that I use called DesktopOK - it saves your icons arrangements, so you can restore to previous arrangement map.

Download at: https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopOK

DesktopOK also has a tool called "Windows Metric" that can modify your Windows icons spacing.

Before you proceed with the next step make sure you save all your work and close all your programs, because to apply the icons spacing change you will have to restart the Windows Explorer and this process might close/terminate some of your programs and you may loose your work.

From the menu go to "Tools" > "Windows Metric". Press the "Default" button and then press  "Restart Explorer".
Now all your icons should be returned to the default spacing.

Here's a guide at SoftwareOK: https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=109

Icons in programs should also be back to normal spacing - e.g.: AIDA64 Extreme, and any other that have icon based UI.
For best results do a system restart to clear any cached items!

**P.S.:** The best thing using DesktopOK is that you don't have to touch the registry!

Also do this at your own responsibility. I'm not responsible for you using this software!